# Using Scipy.signal.filtfilt with vectorization

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I would like to filter a squared matrix A of signals . Each array line is a signal (with nbSamples) and each column is a set of samples of these signals. Filtering must only be applied on a specific signals list.

Here is the array :

```
A = [S0_0, S0_1, S0_2, ... S0_J ...
     S1_0, S1_1, S1_2, ... S1_J ...
     ...
     SI_0, SI_1, SI_2, ... SI_J ...
     ...
     SN_0, SN_1, SN_2, ... SN_J ...]
```

SI is signal number (I+1) and SI_J is sample number (J+1) of signal number (I+1).

I've just learned that numpy.r_ can make vectorization stuff. So I tried this to apply filtering on a specific list of signals number (lines) :

```
B = numpy.zeros(...);
num, den = scipy.signal.butter(...)
signalsNumber = 0:5,10:20
B[numpy.r_[signalsNumber]][0:nbSamples] = scipy.signal.filtfilt(num, den, A[numpy.r_[signalsNumber]][0:nbSamples])
```

But it does not work, I mean there is no error but matrix B remains unchanged, it only contains zeros...

I'm sure I'm not using filtfilt properly but I can't find my error...

Comment: Use the `axis` argument of the [filtfilt](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.filtfilt.html#scipy-signal-filtfilt) to perform the filtering along that dimension,

Comment: I've tried with axis = 0 and axis = 1 but without success !